# Removing secured site programmatically spoils other bindings

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, https, web

I have service which clears unused sites.

```
using (var serverMgr = new ServerManager())
{
    var sitename = $"site-{instanceName}";

    if (IsWebsiteExists(serverMgr, sitename))
    {
        logger.Debug($"Deleting instance '{sitename}' from www server...");
        var site = serverMgr.Sites.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == sitename);
        if (site != null)
        {
            serverMgr.Sites.Remove(site);
        }

        var appPool = serverMgr.ApplicationPools.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == sitename);
        if (appPool != null)
        {
            serverMgr.ApplicationPools.Remove(appPool);
        }
        serverMgr.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Code above works as expected but spoils other sites which uses the same certificate. Other sites just unexpectedly have unselected certificate in https binding and they stop working. This is really annoying.

Why? Is it bug in my code or should I change it? Is it IIS bug?

Comment: are you using hostname filtering in your bindings? have you tried removing the bindings first?

Comment: Yes. Each site is for one tenant. Each tenant has own application working under subdomain. Each site has also own apppool. All sites work under one domain and I have one wildcard ssl certificate. I do not deleted bindings first but it sounds weird.

Comment: bindings are configured at site level, so I'd really try getting rid of them 1st if they screw things up for you. Can you try this please? stop the site, delete the ssl binding and delete the site?

Comment: This behavior also seems to depend on OS and/or IIS version: I did not have this problem when testing it on a Windows 10 system, but it started occurring on a Windows Server system.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all bindings before removing the site:

```
using (var iisManager = new ServerManager)
{
    Site site = iisManager.Sites[siteName];
    site.Bindings.Clear();
    iisManager.CommitChanges();

    site = iisManager.Sites[siteName];
    iisManager.Sites.Remove(site);
    iisManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

It is important to call `CommitChanges` after removing the bindings. Also, you have to query the site again afterwards, or you will get `InvalidOperationException`.

Also, using this approach, you don't get `NotImplementedException` on some systems when calling `CommitChanges` after removing the site, so it solves two annoying problems at once.

If you are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later, you may also use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802922/2279059

Answer (score 1):

Site class represents all common methods and properties for Site in IIS. Also all configuration is done by Nested Types. This Implicate: We have no Way to create new NestedObject, we must get it from factory(ServerManager) and it will have all what it need probably from some static crap(in IIS case even worse)

Our Goal is to delete site, without affecting, nested Type responsible for certificates. That Type is Binding. Site Has readonly Binding Property, which returns BindingCollection this is the place where nesting Happens. This collection is shared by everyone who need Binding. Also everyone can screw others. i.e. ServerManager creates Site object for us, deeper something somehow(IIS c# clone) creates bindings objects for our specific Site object. When you deleting Site object, is removed from IIS, and also Bindings objects for this Site Object are deleting too. IIS does this via own interface, also c# code must too, and have to prevent us to change this behaviour(only IIS team can change it i think ;)). But we can deffend against this nonsens ;)

Try code like this:

```
       Site site = _server.Sites[name];
       if (site == null)
         return;

       var bindings = site.Bindings.ToList();

       foreach (Binding binding in bindings)
       {
          site.Bindings.Remove(binding, true);
       }
          _server.Sites.Remove(site);

          _server.CommitChanges();
```

Remove(binding, true) removes only configuration, not the binding itself. Its neww feature, requiers actual Microsoft.Web.Administrative MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt668014(v=vs.90).aspx

Before this feature this was nice solution:
"Serialize" Binding object, and put it back - not like usually just save somwhere data which are required for Add Binding. Dictionary? MemoryStream? doesn't matter. Big Picture:

Wana delete page with shared bindings ? 
Find all pages which share those bindings, remeber them.
"Serialize" bindings.
Delete page.
Iterate over collection of previously finded Sites, put the bindings back to everyone. i.e. one iteration may look: _siteFromColletion.Bindings.Add(bindingInfo, certHash, certStorename)

bindingInfo is string
certHash byte array
certStorename is string
All you need to add binding with certifcate to Site

HND!

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to remove bindings using overload with 'removeOnlyConfig' parameter but project do not compile. I have the newest version of Microsoft.Web.Administration, vs2015 tell me there is overload but can't compile. Wrrrr...

Comment: Ok. I think that I found solution.

Comment: It seems that `Microsoft.Web.Administration` cannot be upgraded to the latest version without also increasing the target .NET framework version to 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to delete bindings configuration section itself. Internally removes the part of configuration section from xml but only inside this website. Your answer Kamil gave me a hint.

```
using (var serverMgr = new ServerManager())
{
    if (IsWebsiteExists(serverMgr, sitename))
    {
        var site = serverMgr.Sites.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == sitename);
        if (site != null)
        {
            logger.Trace($"Stopping site '{sitename}'...");
            site.Stop();
            logger.Trace($"Deleting bindings collection for '{sitename}'...");

            site.Bindings.Delete(); // <-- deleting bindings config section itself
        }
        serverMgr.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not remove the site. I tried removing the site after calling `site.Bindings.Delete`, and the problem persists.